# if mail ID not found from service error message show angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When I login, enter the mail id and password and then give submit. If the mail id is not there at service, How can I show error message in angularjs.

```
<form name="loginForm">
    <div class="container loginPage">
      <div class="loginForm">
        <div class="formField">
            <div class="formBlk">
                <label><span>Email</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="textBox" name="userEmail" ng-model="userEmail.isLoggedIn" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formField">
            <div class="formBlk">
                <label><span>Passcode</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="textBox" name="password" ng-model="password" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" ng-click="loginUser()" ng-disabled="loginForm.userEmail.$pristine || loginForm.userEmail.$invalid || loginForm.userEmail.$error.email && loginForm.password.$pristine || loginForm.password.$invalid || loginForm.password.$error.password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Allright, so where is the question?

Comment: I need a error message when submit, mail id is not found from service.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: how can I show error message when submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can show error message in your form using div, binding it with ng-show directive similar like below :

```
<div id="formErrors" ng-show="emailInvalid"><ul><li class="error">{{message }}</li></ul></div>
```

If you want to show field level you can use below directive on filed:

```
<input type="email" class="textBox" name="userEmail" ng-model="userEmail.isLoggedIn" value="" autocomplete="off" ng-class="{ 'hasError': loginForm.userEmail.$invalid }" required>
```

Comment: I need a "emailInvalid" function

Comment: This you can set in your controller either true or false depending on your business logic or you can use this one - loginForm.userEmail.$invalid

Comment: I have updated the answer with ng-class directive. you can check in angular docs as well to see more example. Try to use ng-class with ng-pattern.